# does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments

Tags: c#, winforms

I've searched a few topics about this but I'm still stuck, I'm fairly new to c# and this error is starting to give me a headache. I'm trying to Initilise a list but i keep getting that error message. Any help is very welcome.

```
public static List<BookOperator> CreateBookOperators()     
    {
         List<BookOperator> ops = new List<BookOperator>();

        BookOperator op = new BookOperator(ops);
        ops.Add(op);

        return ops;
   }
```

Comment: Did you debug it? Where is the error thrown? It could be your BookOperator class that doesn't have a constructor taking 1 argument

Comment: @MaximeR.C that is a compiler error, so you can't "debug" it in the debugger...

Comment: Can you include the signatures (`public BookOperator(...)`) for all constructors for your BookOperator class?

Comment: What is `BookOperator` ? does if *have* a constructor that takes a parameter? By default, a type only has a *parameterless* constructor.

Comment: I commented too fast haha, but the compiler must be pointing out a specific line tho

Comment: Why does the list element (to be), `BookOperator`, need a reference to the `List<>` instance, when constructed? What *is* a book operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like there is no reason to try and pass the list to the book-operator. Even money says:

```
public static List<BookOperator> CreateBookOperators()     
{
    List<BookOperator> ops = new List<BookOperator>();
    BookOperator op = new BookOperator();
    ops.Add(op); 
    return ops;
}
```

or more tersely:

```
public static List<BookOperator> CreateBookOperators() {
    return new List<BookOperator> {
        new BookOperator()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

it means that your class `BookOperator`  doesn't have any constructor that is taking one arguement. if you can show the code for BookOperator it would be helpful. I guess you need this, i am saying so because your current code doesn't makes any sense. You are passing list as a parameter to class and adding your same class to list. Loop doesn't makes sense to me

```
 BookOperator op = new BookOperator();
 ops.Add(op)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the BookOperator object need to know its owner then the BookOperator needs at least 1 argument in its constructor.

```
public class BookOperator
{
    public List<BookOperator> BookOperators { get; private set; }
    public BookOperator(List<BookOperator> bookOperators)
    {
        BookOperators = bookOperators;
    }
}
```